# How do I hack this ctOS box in the middle of the bottom island?

Tags: watch-dogs

I've decided I've spent *way* too much time figuring out how to access this box to hack it, so it's time to ask somebody. These is this one ctOS Breach in Brandon Docks that's just throwing me for a loop, and I'm wondering if anybody is familiar with the specific location and could tell me how you go about hacking it.

[image: Location on the Map]

[image: Preview of the Location]

As you can see from the second screenshot, it is buried up on top of a building behind those barbed wire fences. Things I've tried:

- I've run around the building many times and found no direct way to physically get up there.
- None of the cameras around the building are high enough up to see it, and there are no other tall buildings nearby that would be able to see it.
- I did run down to L-Train Station (directly to the East) to climb onto the tracks and run all the way back down to the building. This lets me *see* the box on the roof - it's on the wall to the left of those two tall windows as I expected - but being on the tracks puts me too far away from it to be able to hack it.
- The opposite side of the building is completely blocked by a massive billboard.

Ok, so, I must be missing something very obvious here somewhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research on it and found this [video](https://youtu.be/UKodP3pTu6w).

You grab a truck and drive it in the front of the ledge. Since you can climb on the truck, you can easily pull yourself up from the truck roof.

Comment: Awesome! From the angle on the street it's hard to tell there's an actual opening there that you'd think about climbing up there and well, my game did not conveniently place a tall truck right there in the parking lot like in that video. I had to go drive around and look for one. But it worked!